# Using Javascript / Jquery to change text in div upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

here is the array

```
var copyText= [
'this is the first line',
'Simply put, the second line',
'impressed by the third line.'
    ];
```

These don't work ...

```
$("#thisbutton").click(function () {
$("#thetext").innerHTML("meow meow");
});
```

or

```
$("#thisbutton").click(function () {
$("#thetext").innerHTML(copyText[1]);
});
```

or

```
$("#thisbutton").click(function () {
$("#thetext").text(copyText[1]);
});


$("#thisbutton").click(function () {
$("#thetext").html(copyText[1]);
});
```

What I am missing?  thks.

Comment: Please post the rest of the source code on the page. Also, you probably want to wrap the whole thing in $(function(){ //code here });

Comment: thanks, yes thats it.   what about href and a links, how can a javascript array be accessed?   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var htmlLinks= [
   'http://cnn.com',
   'http://youtube.com',
   'http://facebook.com'
  ];

});
</script>
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[0];</script>" target="_blank"> link1 </a> \ 
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[1];</script>" target="_blank"> link2 </a> \ 
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[2];</script>" target="_blank"> link3 </a>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `innerHTML` is a native `DOMElement` property, not a `jQuery` method.
`jQuery`'s `html` method is the equivalent.

Secondly, you are not wrapping this in a `ready` handler:

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var copyText= [
   'this is the first line',
   'Simply put, the second line',
   'impressed by the third line.'
  ];
  $("#thisbutton").click(function () {
     $("#thetext").text(copyText[1]);
  });

});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/McSLM/)**

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var copyText= [
   'this is the first line',
   'Simply put, the second line',
   'impressed by the third line.'
  ];
  $("#thisbutton").click(function () {
     $("#thetext").text(copyText[1]);
  });

});
</script>
<div id="thetext">Hello</div>
<!-- <div id="thisbutton"> <img src="images/btn.jpg" alt="pp"></div>-->
<input type="button" id="thisbutton" value="Click" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: if I use "meow meow", the code works but not array element of copyText[1]   why not the value of the array element ?

Comment: what about href and a links, how can a javascript array be accessed?   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var htmlLinks= [
   'http://cnn.com',
   'http://youtube.com',
   'http://facebook.com'
  ];

});
</script>
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[0];</script>" target="_blank"> link1 </a> \ 
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[1];</script>" target="_blank"> link2 </a> \ 
<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[2];</script>" target="_blank"> link3 </a>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="thetext">

    </div>
    <input type="button" id="thisbutton" value="Click" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#thisbutton").click(function () { $("#thetext").html("meow meow"); });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could not get it to work...<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var copyText= [
   'this is the first line',
   'Simply put, the second line',
   'impressed by the third line.'
  ];
  $("#thisbutton").click(function () {
     $("#thetext").text(copyText[1]);
  });

});
</script>
<div id="thetext">Hello</div>
<!-- <div id="thisbutton"> <img src="images/btn.jpg" alt="pp"></div>-->
<input type="button" id="thisbutton" value="Click" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: how about if you had to access the array element for an href ....<a href="<script type="text/javascript">htmlLinks[0];</script>" target="_blank"> link1 </a> \ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the complete div try replaceWith() jquery function

```
 $("#thetext").replaceWith("htmldata");
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/